# HubSection Header

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I try to do everything in code without XAML. I set HubSections like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  var s = new HubSection
  {
    Name = countries[i],
    Header = "More...",
    //IsHeaderInteractive = true,
    Width = 500,
    Height = 420,
    Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = 
      new BitmapImage(new Uri($"ms-appx:///Assets/Im0{i}.jpg")) }
  };
  hub.Sections.Add(s);
  s.Tapped += (p, e) => OnSectionTapped(s);
}
```

Everything works as I expected. But if I clear the comment on line: IsHeaderInteractive = true, add the line:

```
hub.SectionHeaderClick += hub_SectionHeaderClick;
```

and comment my event binding (s.Tapped +=...), then I see two headers: my header and a default one (with the text "See more..."). My question is: "Why my header is not interactive (it is dead) and the default one is interactive? Default header responds to mouse clicking (tapping?). How to hide the default header?"

Well, some emotions:
I hate XAML and XAML designer. I love code.
How is that happened that JavaScript is much easier to work with than WPF and UWP?

Comment: "Why my header is not interactive (it is dead) and the default one is interactive?" First, by default, the header is NOY interactive, and this is by design. It's like a heading for your content below. "Default header responds to mouse clicking (tapping?)" Yes. "How to hide the default header?" Simply don't specify `Header="xxx"`.